# Select statement to display Minutes in HH:MM Format

Tags: sql-server

I am having a table (Table Name -Production) in SQL Server.The Production table have a Column TimeSpent (Datatype- varchar(25)) and stores Number of minutes spent . Example 60,78,23 etc.
I want to display TimeSpent in HH:MM Format in a select statement. for example it display 01:00 for 60, 01:18 for 78 and so on.
Please help me that how i will write this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tblTime
(
    timespent VARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO #tblTime VALUES (78)
INSERT INTO #tblTime VALUES (60)
INSERT INTO #tblTime VALUES (100)

SELECT 
    CAST(TimeSpent/ 60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(TimeSpent % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS [HH:MM] 
FROM 
    #tblTime
```

Comment: This doesn't have the leading zero for hours, and uses `.` instead of `:` for the separator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Aaron. Have changed dot to colon. But adding leading zero i left it. How would one know whether it needs to be 2 digit or 3 digit? as hours can be anything.

Comment: If it's ore than 99 hours, then that is probably a different problem. But the OP clearly asked for `01:00`, `01:18` etc.